# Main stack space and task stack space

Tags: c++, c, rtos, freertos

I want to know if there any difference between main stack space and a task's stack space. I have taken up a quiz on RTOS in which the following question was asked

*Suppose there is a non static local variable declared in the task function, where exactly the memory for the non static variable is allocated during the execution of task function  ?*

```
void task_function(void *p)

{

 /*this is task function */

int i ; /* non static variable */
}
```

The options given were: a. Main stack space of RAM.  b.Task's stack space.

I want to know if there is a separate **main stack space of RAM** other than the stack space allocated for each task. And if it is then why?

Comment: Beats me.  The thread/s have stacks.  That's where the automatic storage vars go.  That's it for me.  I don't know what 'main stack space' is either:)

Comment: If by _main stack space_ the stack space of the `Main` function is meant, then it is not stored in the main stack space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon startup, there is startup code that runs before `main` gets called.  The startup code puts in place the run-time environment that is required by `main`.  This includes initializing initialized variables, zeroing out uninitialized variables, setting the stack pointer, and, for C++, calling the constructors for statically allocated objects.  So when `main` gets called there is already a stack setup and in use.  I presume this is what the quiz refers to as the "main stack".

For Free-RTOS and other typical RTOS, the RTOS is not setup and running when `main` is called.  Rather, that is typically done within `main` by calling `xTaskCreate` and then `vTaskStartScheduler`.  Each time `main` calls `xTaskCreate` it creates a task and assigns a stack space for that task.  But while `main` is running it is still using the original stack created by the startup code.  Once `vTaskStartScheduler` is called, the RTOS scheduler will perform a context switch to one of the tasks.  The context switch includes changing the stack pointer to the task's stack.  So when the task starts executing it uses it's own stack.

So yes, there is a main stack space that is separate from the tasks' stack spaces.  It is necessary so that `main` can do everything that it does before starting the RTOS scheduler.

Comment: It might be worth noting that on a Cortex-M interrupts also run in the main stack space (CSTACK).

Comment: Well, the Cortex-M Main Stack Pointer (MSP) is a different issue from what I've described.  The Cortex-M supports two stack pointers, MSP and PSP.  If the RTOS makes use of the PSP for tasks then yes the processor switches to the MSP while handling interrupts.  But I don't think that is what this question is about.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is b.   Every thread that executed this function would have the variable i declared on the stack allocated for that thread.  Every thread would have a different stack.

I think the test had some deliberate vague answers to catch out those people who don't know the answer and guessed.